Deriving a metric for how well data fits a specific model in R
Say I had 3 dummy models (image below) and a big set of data across timepoints A,B,C and I wanted to do a test to see how well each individual set of measurements fits each of the 3 models to derive a metric for Model 1,2,3.
How would I do this in R?
dummy model data
dummy.df <- data.frame(S = c(0.8, 0.4, 0.1),
                       P = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.3),
                       R = c(0.1, 0.35, 0.9),
                       row.names = LETTERS[1:3])

dummy input data
random.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(5*3), 
                                  nrow = 5, 
                                  ncol = 3, 
                                  dimnames = list(1:5, LETTERS[1:3])))



You seem to be seeking general data analysis advice. This does not appear to be a specific R programming question. You should probably ask your question at [stats.se] instead. That's the site for statistical help. Once you know the right method to use, you can probably google how to do that in R.

Since your models all have the same number of parameters, R^2 might be a good criterion. If you want a more generalizable criterion, AIC (Akaike Information Criterion) is a pretty standard choice.

Assuming that random.df is the data and dummy.df are the model values, we could compare the sum of squares of the residuals where lower means better fit. For the data in the Note at the end P has the lowest sum of squares of residuals.
s <- stack(random.df); s
colSums((s$values - dummy.df[s$ind, ])^2)
##        S        P        R 
## 2.268878 1.765409 3.389199 

Note
dummy.df <- data.frame(S = c(0.8, 0.4, 0.1),
                       P = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.3),
                       R = c(0.1, 0.35, 0.9),
                       row.names = LETTERS[1:3])
set.seed(123)
random.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(5*3), 
                                  nrow = 5, 
                                  ncol = 3, 
                                  dimnames = list(1:5, LETTERS[1:3])))

